# Is there a Bitcoin exchange which has bank accounts in South Korea?

Tags: exchanges

Is there any exchange, or a website selling Bitcoin, which has a bank account in South Korea?

Answer (score 2):

CryptoXChange.com will let you withdraw KRW directly to your bank account in South Korea. They just opened about a week ago.